Reference to cout is ambiguous in C++
I started learning c++ on www.learncpp.com and in here I read that there is no problem defining our own objects with the name 'cout' or 'cin' since C++ moved all the functionality in the standard library into the std namespace. However, I try to define a global variable named cout and then use it in main but the compiler complains that the reference is ambiguous. And I don't understand why. Can you please explain me why do I have this error?!
Here is the code:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getInteger();
int cout;

int main()
{
    int x{ getInteger() };
    int y{ getInteger() };

    cout = 20;
    std::cout << x << " + " << y << " is " << x + y << '\n';
    return 0;
}

int getInteger()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

The error:
||=== Build: Debug in Chapter2_8 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\CBProjects\Chapter2_8\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\CBProjects\Chapter2_8\main.cpp|13|error: reference to 'cout' is ambiguous|
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\iostream|61|note: candidates are: 'std::ostream std::cout'|
C:\CBProjects\Chapter2_8\main.cpp|6|note:                 'int cout'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|


Just remove using namespace std;. The whole point of this is so that you can say cout instead of std::cout, but if you also have a variable whose real name is cout how is the compiler suppposed to know which you mean?

"I started learning c++ on www.learncpp.com..." I would instead recommend a good c++ book.

Also see What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? that explains exactly the fundamental problem here.

cout = 20; should be ::cout = 20;

An alternative (if you really need to have using namespace std for some reason) is to avoid having a global variable named cout (or any other name of an object in std).     For example, rename it.   When using namespace std is in effect,  both the global ::cout and std::cout are candidate matches to match an identifier cout.   The usage is not relevant to what is a candidate (i.e. the fact of doing cout = 20 does not discard std::cout as an option).  An implementation is required to get down to exactly one candidate BEFORE checking operations, not after.

Read on a bit further. Chapter "Using namespace std (and why to avoid it)" explains the problem with using namespace std; and why it doesn't allow you to use names from std namespace anymore.
By adding using namespace std;, you brought all the names from namespace std into global namespace and now compiler cannot distinguish between your int cout that you declared in the global namespace and std::ostream cout that is also in global namespace due to using namespace std;.

Thanks a lot. I missed that part.
